# Why isn't cron running automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

OS : Ubuntu 12.04

Now I want to use [Backup](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) and [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to automatic backup my database. When I connect the server by ssh as an added user to run **backup perform -t my_backup**,it works well.But the cron file:

```
0 22 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup'
```

can't run at 22:00. When I use **cat /etc/crontab** check the cron's config file,it is:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

The **/bin/bash** and **/bin/sh** are different.What's the reason?How to do?

Comment: What do you call “the cron file”? Is that the output of `crontab -l`? If you add a job `* * * * * echo test`, do you receive an email every minute (remember to turn it off after a couple of minutes)?

Comment: I have add MAILTO=<my_email_address>,but haven't receive a mail.Even added the `* * * * * echo test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special crontab file /etc/crontab has a slightly different format in that the sixth field must be the user the cron job will be run as.  So if you want to put your job into that file, you must insert a user name between * and /bin/bash to match the format.  Something like:

```
0 22 * * * root /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup'
```

replacing root with whatever user name you really want to use.

Comment: yep, either that or JZ should add it to the user's own crontab.  and for completeness, crontab files in /etc/cron.d/ have the same format as /etc/crontab.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have run whenever with rails user which I created by root.I have try your method to add root or rails user name between the * and /bin/bash,but it still doesn't work:-(

Comment: @JingqiangZhang If the command is running and failing, cron should be mailing the user the error messages.  Also, cron itself should be logging its activities somewhere, probably in /var/log.

Comment: The log file /var/log/cron.log has: Sep  3 22:00:01 domain-name CRON[20833]: (rails) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t my_backup'),I don't know why there isn't any result.Also,I didn't receive a mail by cron.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a script with the backup command you want to execute, and then call this in the crontab like:

```
0 22 * * * (cd <absolute-path-of-directory> && ./script.sh >>script.log 2>&1)
```

In this script I recommend first of all a line like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "`date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S':`: $0 started"
```

So you can see that cron is executing it and concentrate on the command. Reasons why scripts don't run under cron that are normally executing fine are often find in the different environment that is used under cron.

Answer (score 0):

i also experienced the same few weeks ago. i was trying to copy and overwrite the crontab file. even though all the parameters were proper, cron was not running as expected. when i removed and copied the same file, it was working fine.. just try the same..

however i did not understand the reason it did not work when i tried to overwrite that file..

Comment: Thank you for your suggest,but I have no luck.

Comment: The safe way to make changes to the crontab is through `crontab -e`, which will open an editor for you and afterwards reload the config. `cron` is under no obligation to monitor if changes have been made behind its back.